# XPath error trying to get data

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, nullreferenceexception

I'm making a C# application and I need to get some data from a website. I'm using XPath to accomplish this.

The website I need to get data from is this one: http://www.iec-iab.be/nl/vennootschappen/d46148d6-10a4-dd11-96ed-005056bd424d

I need to get the email from this page so I copied the XPath of this in chrome

```
//*[@id="WebPartWPQ1"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/span/span/a
```

In my C# application I try to get the value of this with the following code but I get a NullReferenceException

```
string email = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"WebPartWPQ1\"]//div[1]//div[2]//div[4]//span[2]//span//span//a").InnerText;
```

What changes do I need to make so I get the email?

Answer (score 0):

First impression would be

```
string email = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("////*[@id=\"WebPartWPQ1\"]//div[1]//div[2]//div[4]//span[2]//span//span//a").InnerText;
```

Double the starting `/`-es

Comment: I've tried it but it also gives an error: XPathException was unhandled

Comment: Can you catch the error in your debugger and check the message for more information?

Comment: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146231997
  Message=Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
  Source=System.Xml